# How do I stop a find from descending into found directories?

Tags: find, recursive

I'm wanting to find all directories with a specific string so I can do another find on the files contained within.

So I don't want to waste time on `./my-search-term/dir/my-search-term` etc.

How can I stop recursing when I've found the first my-search-term directory?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `-prune` action makes `find` not recurse into the directory. You can combine it with another action such as `-exec` (the order of `-prune` and `-exec` doesn't matter, as long as `-prune` is executed either way).

```
find . -name my-search-term -prune -exec find {} … \;
```

Note that nesting `find` inside a `find -exec` can be a little problematic: you can't use `-exec` in the inner `find`, because the terminator would be seen as a terminator by the outer `find`. You can work around that by invoking a shell, but beware of quoting.

```
find . -name my-search-term -prune -exec sh -c '
    find "$@" … -exec … {\} +
' _ {} +
```

Comment: Are the parentheses in your first command necessary? `-prune` returns *true* and can be put before the `-exec`.

Comment: @rozcietrzewiacz No, they're not necessary. Habit of having a `-o` in there, I guess. And I guess putting `-prune` before `-exec` is more readable.

Comment: Thanks, didn't use the `-prune` option before.

Comment: In my use case, this command: `mkdir -p x1 x2; touch x1/x11 x1/x12 x2/x21 x2/x22; find . -name 'x1*' -exec rm -rf {} \;` gives the error: `find: ./x1: No such file or directory`. The solution is to add `-prune` at the end of `find` command.

Comment: (1) Some versions of `find` expand `{}` even when it appears as a substring of an argument to `-exec`.  Such a version of `find` will choke on your second command, because the `{}` in the inner `find` command (in the shell command) will be replaced by the name of the directory found in the outer `find`.  You can fix that by saying `find . -name my-search-term -prune -exec sh -c 'find "$0" … -exec … "{"} +' {} \;` i.e., using `"{"}`, which the shell will turn into `{}`.   … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (2) But why not go Full Monty?  `find . -name my-search-term -prune -exec sh -c 'find "$@" … -exec … "{"} +' sh {} +` will run a ``find … -exec … +`` inside a ``find … -exec … +``!

Answer (score 9):

### - bare solutions -

If you want `find` to skip the found directory's contents, but continue searching in other directories, use `-prune` as @laebshade suggested. The full command should then look like

```
 find . -type d -name somename -prune -exec ...
```

On the other hand, if you want `find` to entirely **stop searching** and after finding the first matching directory, then what you are looking for is **`-quit`** (available since version `4.2.3` of `GNU find`). This one is a bit more tricky to use, because it makes `find` exit immediately - so `-quit` must be placed at the very end of the command:

```
find . -type d -name somename -exec ... -quit
```

For this to work as expected, one has to assure that the `-exec` returns *true* (in other words, a *zero* status). If you want the exit status of `-exec` to be ignored, so that `-quit` always works, you need a little trick:

```
find . -type d -name somename \( -exec ... -o -true \) -quit
```

or

```
find . -type d -name somename \( -exec ... -o -quit \)
```

or

```
find . -type d -name somename \( -exec ... , -quit \) # a comma before -quit
```

### - some explanation -

The most important thing about how `find` works is that all the actions *("tests")* are treated as **logical predicates** interpreted from left to right. Therefore, the last action (for example `-quit`) will only be performed if the whole previous part did not return *false*. By default, all tests are joined with logical "AND", the `-o` option changes the joint to "OR".

A tricky element of `-o` is that `find` can "optimize" your command and not run the `-exec` part if you type just

```
find . -type d -name somename -exec ... -o -quit
```

To cope with that, you can force `find` to evaluate all the predicates joned with "OR", by enclosing them within parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for, but the "maxdepth" option would not allow the find command to go beyond the current directory. I also think you could add wildcard to your find:

```
$> find /your/dir -name '*mystring*' -maxdepth 1 -type d -exec my_action {} \;
```

-name '*mystring*' will look for all files that match '*mystring*'. do mind the single quotes.
-maxdepth 1 find the files not going past the current directory. -maxdepth 2 would find files in the current directory and on one more level of directories, so on and so forth.
-type d finds the files that are directories. -type f finds regular files, etc.

My 0.02... ^_^